# Convert algorithm from C# to VB.NET fail

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, extension-methods, c#-to-vb.net

I'm trying to convert the following algorithm from C# to VB.NET and the VB.NET I have is not producing the same results as my C# algorithm, can someone tell me where I've gone wrong in my conversion?

```
public static IEnumerable<T[]> Combinations<T>(this IEnumerable<T> elements, int k)
{
    List<T[]> result = new List<T[]>();

    // single combination
    if (k == 0)
    {
        result.Add(new T[0]);
    }
    else
    {
        int current = 1;
        foreach (T element in elements)
        { 
            //combine each element with k-1 combinations of subsequent elements
            result.AddRange(elements
                .Skip(current++)
                .Combinations(k - 1)
                .Select(combination => (new T[] { element }).Concat(combination).ToArray())
                );
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

This is what I've got in VB.NET:

```
<Extension()>
Public Function Combinations(Of T)(ByRef elements As IEnumerable(Of T), ByVal k As Integer) As IEnumerable(Of T())

    Dim result As New List(Of T())()

    'single combination'
    If k = 0 Then
        result.Add(New T(-1) {})
    Else
        Dim current As Integer = 0

        For Each element As T In elements
            'combine each element with k - 1 combinations of subsequent elements'
            Dim local As T = element
            result.AddRange(elements.Skip(current = current + 1).Combinations(k - 1).Select(Function(combs) (New T() {local}).Concat(combs).ToArray()))
        Next
    End If

    Return result
End Function
```

Something is wrong, but I'm not sure what, I'm guessing the problem is somewhere in the lambda.

Can anybody point out what I've done wrong with my conversion?

Comment: Do you have unit tests for the original method? If not, write some, and then run them against the converted version too.

Answer (score 2):

Use a code converter...

```
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension> _
Public Shared Function Combinations(Of T)(elements As IEnumerable(Of T), k As Integer) As IEnumerable(Of T())
    Dim result As New List(Of T())()

    ' single combination
    If k = 0 Then
        result.Add(New T(-1) {})
    Else
        Dim current As Integer = 1
        For Each element As T In elements
            'combine each element with k-1 combinations of subsequent elements

            result.AddRange(elements.Skip(System.Math.Max(System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(current),current - 1)).Combinations(k - 1).[Select](Function(combination) (New T() {element}).Concat(combination).ToArray()))
        Next
    End If

    Return result
End Function
```

Comment: This is doing some stuff that doesn't seem to be in the original code...  `Max(Interlocked.Increment(current), current - 1)` for one...

Comment: That's the equivalent of `current++`.

Comment: @Daniel: I just wrote and ran this C# console application: `int i = 5; Console.WriteLine(i++); Console.WriteLine(i++); Console.WriteLine(Math.Max(Interlocked.Increment(ref i), i - 1));`.  It output `5 6 8`.  Doesn't look equivalent to me.  `Min(Increment(i), i - 1)` might work, though, except for where `i` overflows (though I guess VB would throw an exception there, since math is checked by default.  Not to mention his algorithm would die).  Point is, they are not equivalent.

Comment: @Merlyn: so why does my algo produce the right outcome then? VB doesn't have Undefined Behaviour, or does it?

Comment: @Tony: I'm as confused as you are.  Nothing about `Max(Increment(i), i - 1)` makes any sense to me as a conversion of `i++`.  It should get the max of either "i incremented" or "i incremented - 1", which should logically always be "i incremented".  It's also a little hacky (I guess you could argue that the post-increment operator is, too).  And any standard language by definition has UB :)

Comment: I posted a question on it... perhaps we can clarify it that way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert on VB at all, but the problem might stem from either:

`current = current + 1` is not the same as `current++`.  It is (basically) the same as `++current`.  These have way different behavior.

Since VB doesn't support inline post-increment operators directly, the closest bug-free implementation I can think of is (in C#, since I don't know VB):

```
int current = 0;
Func<int> getCurrentThenIncrement = () =>
{
    int previous = current;
    current = current + 1;
    return previous;
};

// ...
.Skip(getCurrentThenIncrement())
```

Or, it could stem from:

```
Public Function Combinations(Of T)(ByRef elements ...
```

When I use .Net Reflector to look at it and "convert" it to VB, `elements` seems to be `ByVal`.

Answer (score 0):

There’s no need for the in-place increment of current at all, as far as I can see. Just increment it *after* the Linq expression. On the other hand, you should initialise `current` with `1`, same as in C#.

Furthermore, your “base case” is a bit weird; you can just write this:

```
result.Add(New T() { })
```

No need for the `-1`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a compiler on hand to check, but I would convert it like this:

```
<Extension()>
Public Function Combinations(Of T)(elements As IEnumerable(Of T), k As Integer) As IEnumerable(Of T())

    Dim result As New List(Of T())()

    ' single combination
    If k = 0 Then
        result.Add(New T() {})
    Else
        Dim current As Integer = 1
        For Each element As T In elements
            'combine each element with k-1 combinations of subsequent elements
            result.AddRange(elements
                .Skip(PostfixInc(current))
                .Combinations(k - 1)
                .Select(Function(combination) (New T() { element }).Concat(combination).ToArray())
                )
        Next
    End If
    Return result

End Function

Private Function PostfixInc(ByRef value As Integer) As Integer

    Dim currentValue = value
    value += 1
    Return currentValue

End Function
```

That's as direct a conversion of each syntax element as I can think of right now. Once you have it working, then think about cleaning it up (e.g. try to remove side effects from the LINQ expression).

**EDIT:**

Differences from your code:

- `New T(-1) {}` should be `New T() {}`.
- `current` should be initialised to 1 not 0.
- `Skip(current = current + 1)` will not do what you want. In fact, it does nothing, because `current = current + 1` is a boolean expression that will always evaluate to false. VB.NET will silently convert false to 0 if option strict is off, or throw a compiler error if option strict is on.