# operator++ in VB.NET - Interlocked.Increment

Tags: c#, vb.net, c#-to-vb.net

Per the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6174043/convert-algorithm-from-c-to-vb-net-fail), one of the answers seems to imply that by using a code converter from C# to VB.NET, that the operator++ applied to an int should be replaced by `System.Math.Max(System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(current),current - 1))`, I wondered if this is actually correct?

If so, why is it correct?  I didn't think that operator++ would be implemented as an Interlocked.Increment operation?  I didn't even think it was threadsafe.  I'm failing to see who these two are the same, and then why the answer to the question linked to, even works?

I tried it and it produces the correct result.  AFAIK, .NET has no such thing as undefined behaviour, as C++ does.

Can anybody clarify?

Comment: I was the one that provided the answer in the other question. Just for the reference: I used [telerik's converter](http://converter.telerik.com/).

Comment: You are write, there is no need for using interlocked.increment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do `x += 1` in VB.Net. Not as elegant as x++, but better than x = x + 1.

Interlocked.Increment is for making your add operation thread-safe. You may not need it at all.

EDIT: Also, if it wasn't clear, there is no ++ operator in VB, I don't get why, but well...

Comment: I think the reason there is no "++" in VB is exactly because you can use x += 1. In VB terseness of source code is not a prime concern (cf. all that Not And Or Then End Do stuff which C/C++ renders as punctuation) -- except in the case of the With statement, which C/C++ could usefully use!

Comment: Having ++ may come handy in some cases, even more if allowing not only post-increment/decrement, but pre-increment/decrement as well.

Comment: x+=1 is quite different from x++. The latter returns a value. There's no real value in ++ and -- other than making a language needlessly complex.

Comment: I do not agree with it, as I said, pre and post incrementors/decrementos come handy in several situations. Of course, they don't make anything you cannot achieve by other means, but the same could be said about a lot of features out there.

Comment: Actually, @DavidHeffernan, you just said yourself why it *IS* valuable- the fact that the latter returns a value. Wishing right now VB.NET could do that. :(

Comment: @KTF The fact that you can return a value is the problem. Witness the endless x++ - --y++ + ++z++ questions asked about C and C++.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I don't think poor use of a language feature and number of questions asked has anything to do with it's value. Witness the endless questions asked about computer science, or any other complex field. :)

Comment: @KTF VB can do it; it's just not built-in: `Function PreInc(ByRef Value As Integer) As Integer : Value += 1 : PreInc = Value : End Function` `Function PostInc(ByRef Value As Integer) As Integer : PostInc = Value : Value += 1 : End Function`. And you could make these Extension methods, and even with a default `One` parameter `= 1`.

Comment: @Mark Hurd, yes you can do it with VB, as with just about any OO language, but I think you missed my point. However, I think your response reminds me that it's not a big deal.

Answer (score 3):

C# operator++ does not use interlocked semantics. It is equivalent to `x=x+1`.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not a correct replacement for `current++` because `current++` returns the unchanged value of `current` (post-increment), while

```
System.Math.Max(System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(current),current - 1))
```

returns the incremented value (pre-increment).

I got this same code from a C# to VB converter http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/ and that difference changed the behavior of the program.

Comment: I mean the unchanged value should be pre increment and the incremented value should be post increment unless my english is wrong